# Unable to use DOMDocument in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, domdocument

I have been unable to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in symfony. After digging around, I found the problem might be that I do not have the php xml extension, but I thought that it was absurd because, despite no being able to use DOMDocument, I can use Symfony's [DOMCrawler](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_addHtmlContent), which obviously uses something similar to DOMDocument. Well, After looking through Crawler's source code, I found they uses something like

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', $charset);
```

instead of the usual

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', $charset);
```

Does someone know the difference between the two, and why one works and the other doesn't in Symfony?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in symfony we use namespace in each class. 
And because you have declared a namespace in your class then you need to inform PHP about the namespaces of each class you want to use. If you do not declare the namespace of a class you are using, PHP will think this class is in the same namespace than the current class.

So the backslash `"\"` in this code: `new \DOMDocument()` is there to informe PHP that you want to use the DOMDocument class from the "global" namespace. 
If you want to use the Datetime object you will also need to use a backslash when instantiating the Datetime object.

Another solution is to declare with the keyword `Use`. 
For exemple:

```
use \DOMDocument;
```

And then in your code you will instanciate without backslash: `new DomDocument()`